# Vuetify Button Group + TipTap editor

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a toolbar using Vuetify for this text editor:
https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap

My issue here is that TipTap has methods to check for editor status.
e.g. `isActive.bold()`
TipTap also uses commands to toggle status of formats `commands.italic`

While the button groups in Vuetify wants to have an array of values.

```
<v-btn-toggle multiple v-model="format">
  <v-btn :value="1" @click="commands.bold">
    <v-icon>mdi-format-bold</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn :value="2" @click="commands.italic">
    <v-icon>mdi-format-italic</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn :value="3" @click="commands.strike">
    <v-icon>mdi-format-strikethrough</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
```

I'm coming up short on how to combine these two approaches.

I've tried to create a computed v-model field to bind the button group to and somehow compute the array to bind using the status methods.

The Vuetify button groups seems overly complicated to work with.
Just having a `isPressed/Toggled/Checked` prop on the button would have solved this a lot easier.

Thoughts here?